# Ionic3 Push notification com firebase

Tags: ionic, push-notification

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o plug in de push do ionic , com firebase 
mas ele ta pedindo pra mim  fazer uma coisa . mas não to conseguindo achar e resolver

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
    -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
```

[image: image aqui!]

tenho xcode no meu mac